# Find a value within nested array using Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I  have an Array formtted like:

```
 myArray = [{
        "urlTag": "Google",
        "urlTitle": "Users",
        "status": 6,
        "nested": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "http:\/\/www.google.com",
        }
    },
    {
        "urlTag": "Bing",
        "tabTitle": "BingUsers"
    }]
```

I know the urlTag, and based on that, i need to get the title that is nested inside the `nested` array.

currently I have:

```
    let myUrl = 'Google';
    let myResult = _.result(_.find(myArray, {'urlTag': url}), nested.title);
```

I need `myResult` to be `http:\/\/www.google.com` but it's empty.

Comment: You need to quote the path: `_.result(_.find(myArray, {'urlTag': url}), 'nested.title');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [result()](https://lodash.com/docs#result) or [get()](https://lodash.com/docs#get) do the job. The only difference is that `result()` will invoke the path if it resolves to a function:

```
_.get(_.find(myArray, { urlTag: myUrl }), 'nested.title');
// → "http://www.google.com"

_.result(_.find(myArray, { urlTag: myUrl }), 'nested.title');
// → "http://www.google.com"
```